# SaveAsTextFile: Empty file causes Spark streaming exception

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, spark-streaming

I am using SparkStreaming and it took me quite some time to find the root cause of this issue.

In my source code I am writing variables to HDFS with `saveAsTextFile`:

```
variable.coalesce(1,true).saveAsTextFile("/user/root/vector/training/")
```

I understood that for each partition a file is created, see: [What are the files generated by Spark when using “saveAsTextFile”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23898098/what-are-the-files-generated-by-spark-when-using-saveastextfile). The _SUCCESS file is always empty.

I was running the example code from the [Spark KMeans Streaming algorithm](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/mllib-clustering.html#streaming-k-means). Here is the log right before the exception:

```
[info] 2016-04-23 18:55:10 INFO  FileInputDStream:58 - New files at time 1461430510000 ms:
[info] hdfs://cluster:8020/user/root/vector/training/_SUCCESS
[info] hdfs://cluster:8020/user/root/vector/training/part-00000
[info] 2016-04-23 18:55:10 INFO  MemoryStore:58 - Block broadcast_0 stored as values in memory (estimated size 258.0 KB, free 258.0 KB)
[info] 2016-04-23 18:55:10 INFO  MemoryStore:58 - Block broadcast_0_piece0 stored as bytes in memory (estimated size 21.2 KB, free 279.2 KB)
[info] 2016-04-23 18:55:10 INFO  BlockManagerInfo:58 - Added broadcast_0_piece0 in memory on localhost:56035 (size: 21.2 KB, free: 743.2 MB)
[info] 2016-04-23 18:55:10 INFO  SparkContext:58 - Created broadcast 0 from textFileStream at streaming-kmeans.scala:35
[info] 2016-04-23 18:55:10 ERROR JobScheduler:95 - Error generating jobs for time 1461430510000 ms
[info] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.InvalidInputException: Input path does not exist: hdfs://cluster:8020/user/root/vector/training/_SUCCESS
```

It worked perfectly when I just copied part-00000 to HDFS. Obviously Spark Streaming tries to process the empty file but fails in doing so. I looked up the APIs for textFileStream and saveAsTextFile but could not find a good approach to tell Spark not to detect empty files.

Isn't this a common problem in other scenarios as well? 
I don't want to write to another directory first and then move all the non-empty files to my Spark streaming destination. Better ideas?

Comment: can you share more code? looks like you added _SUCCESS to your input