# How to convert .crc files created by saveAsTextFile() to .txt file

Tags: python, pyspark

I'm trying to save my pyspark output into .txt file for future reference. So I wrote following code

```
fileName=names1[i]+".txt" # Generating file name as fieldname.txt
    #data1.groupby(names1[i]).agg(F.collect_set("name")).rdd.saveAsTextFile(names1[i]+'.txt') 
    data.groupby(names1[i]).agg(F.collect_set("name")).rdd.saveAsTextFile(fileName)
```

But after running the code I'm seeing folders with variable filename. Say if my filename is abc.txt then I'm seeing folder name as abc.txt and under that folder lots of file with .crc extension. How can I group those .crc file into .txt file? Either by pyspark or Manually

Comment: This might help..https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23898098/what-are-the-files-generated-by-spark-when-using-saveastextfile

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are the files generated by Spark when using "saveAsTextFile"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23898098/what-are-the-files-generated-by-spark-when-using-saveastextfile)

Comment: Suggesting as a duplicate because it answers your question: you don't need to, you're interested in `part-` files without extension.

Comment: No, it is not duplicate. I saw that post. That post is giving description of files generated by Spark when using "SaveAsTextFile". My question is how to retrieve the text file that I want to generate using saveAsTextFile for saving my data