# Saving a parquet file in java

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, parquet

I have `myDataset` variable of type `Dataset<Row>`.

When i try to save this to a parquet file using `myDataset.write().format("parquet").save(output_dir_path)` ,where `output_dir_path` is a String with path for the generated file, something like this is generated

`part-00000-ba364392-3bbe-46fd-aa34-ddca56001ceb-c000.snappy.parquet`

Can anyone please explain how java names this file and can i produce file with specific name with `write()` method somehow?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23898098/what-are-the-files-generated-by-spark-when-using-saveastextfile

Comment: that's how Spark name the files. you cannot change this behaviour of spark, but you can renmae the files afterwards.